# How to dynamically work with dialog TextBoxes in dm-script

Tags: textbox, dialog, dm-script

How do I set and get the text of a `TextBox` in a dialog in dm-script?

---

Check out the following example dialog. It creates a dialog that contains a `TextBox`. I want to set the value of this `TextBox` on creation. And I want to modify (get and set) the value on a function call, say a button click.

As shown in the given code, I tried `DLGValue()`, `DLGTitle()`, and `DLGLabel()`. But none of them worked. How do I do this?

Note: The *Show* button shows the current `TagGroup` representing the `TextBox`. I was hoping for seeing something, either on initial state or after the element has changed. But I couldn't find anything.

```c
class ExampleDialog : UIFrame{
    number counter;
    TagGroup field;
    
    void addText(object self){
        string msg = "Added text the " + counter + "-th time.\n";
        string current_text = field.DLGGetStringValue();
        field.DLGValue(current_text + "Value: " + msg);
        field.DLGTitle(current_text + "Title: " + msg);
        field.DLGLabel(current_text + "Label: " + msg);
        result(msg);
        
        field.DLGInvalid(1);
        self.validateView();
        
        counter++;
    }
    
    void showTg(object self){
        field.TagGroupOpenBrowserWindow(0);
    }
    
    object init(object self){
        TagGroup dlg, dlg_items;
        
        counter = 1;
        
        dlg = DLGCreateDialog("Example", dlg_items);
        
        dlg.DLGAddElement(DLGCreatePushButton("Update", "addText"));
        dlg.DLGAddElement(DLGCreatePushButton("Show", "showTg"));
        
        field = DLGCreateTextBox(100, 10, 1);
        field.DLGValue("Value: Initial");
        field.DLGTitle("Title: Initial");
        field.DLGLabel("Label: Initial");
        dlg.DLGAddElement(field);
        
        self.super.init(dlg);
        return self;
    }
}

alloc(ExampleDialog).init().pose();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do:

---

```c
    class handler : UIFrame {
        void ShowText( object self ) {
            string str = self.GetTextElementData("textBox");
            result( "text box :[" + str + "]\n");
            return;
        };
        void SetText( object self ) {
            string str = ""
            for(number i=0;i<100;i++) str+=CHR(64+Random()*26);
            self.SetTextElementData("textBox",str);
            return;
        };
    };
    
    number boxWidth = 40, boxHeight = 4, txtLength = 160;
    
    TagGroup Dialog = DLGCreateDialog( "text box");
    TagGroup txtScript = DLGCreateTextBox( boxWidth, BoxHeight, txtLength ).DLGIdentifier( "textBox" );
    TagGroup tgButton1 = DLGCreatePushButton( "Set random text", "SetText" );
    TagGroup tgButton2 = DLGCreatePushButton( "show text in result window", "ShowText" );
    Dialog.DLGAddElement( tgButton1 );
    Dialog.DLGAddElement( tgButton2 );
    Dialog.DLGAddElement( txtScript );
    alloc(handler).init(Dialog).pose();
```

Comment: Works perfectly, as always. Thank you very much.